# Debug a .NET UserControl running in SIMATIC WinCC

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am currently developing a .NET UserControl for WinCC. To do that, I wrote a WinForms UserControl and tested it in a small WinForms Application. Everything worked great.

Then I inserted my Control into my WinCC Picture and ran that. Somehow, my Control behaves different in WinCC. So I tried attaching my Visual Stuido 2012 to the WinCC runtime process (PdlRT.exe) and set a breakpoint inside a button click event handler. After attaching, the breakpoint was disabled and the tooltip `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

So I moved my DLL and PDB file to various folders, just in case that WinCC copies my dll and ignores the PDB file. I tried the root folder of WinCC runtime, as well as the root folder of all pictures.
Different .NET Framework version didn't help either.

Are there any properties or settings that need to be set if I want to debug a control that is hostet by another processs? Or does WinCC have some characteristics that need attention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After talking to Siemnes' WinCC Hotline, I finally got it figured out:

- Make sure your DLL is compiled as x86
- In the DLL project settings, check "Enable native code debugging" option
- When attaching to WinCC, set the code type to Native and Managed (v4.5, v4.0)

I hope this will help someone at some point ;)

Comment: Hi I am developing controls for WinCC V15 Pro. I'm having trouble getting them to render properly in designer view. In runtime the controls look like they should. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. The only thing is could advise you to is changing to x86 when using the designer